# Раскрывающийся список select и несколько баз данных

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть объект organisations, содержащий в каждой ячейке объект, включающий в себя наименование организации, ИНН, ОГРН и адрес, примерно так:

```
organisations = [

{
    name:"ООО «КБМ»",
    inn:"5018048203",
    ogrn:"1025002031405",
    address:"141075, Московская обл., г. Королев, пр. Космонавтов, д. 12А",
    address1:"129110, г. Москва, ул. Гиляровского д. 65, стр. 1, пом. XVI Ч., ком. 39, эт. 5",
    nameLong:"ООО Компания «Большая Медведица»"
},

{
    name:"ООО «АТЕ ФУД»",
    inn:"7731284520",
    ogrn:"1157746508040",
    address:"121596, Город Москва, Улица Горбунова, Дом 2, Строение 204, Комната 48"    
},

{
    name:"ООО «Смартори»",
    inn:"7733223201",
    ogrn:"1157746154312",
    address:"125445, город Москва, шоссе Ленинградское, дом 112, корпус 4"  
}

]
```

Есть еще массивы persons and arbitrationManagers аналогичного вида. Длина массивов динамическая и заранее неизвестная.

Я создал раскрывающийся список select следующего вида, содержащий Все 3 массива: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь мне нужно написать onchange функцию - обработчик события и повесить на раскрывающийся список так, чтобы он выбрал один из трех соответствующих массивов, затем соответствующую позицию в массиве и затем данные из него подставил в документ. Как это оптимальнее всего реализовать?

P.S.: функция для составления списка. Аргументы: `exportList` = лист, который строится, `dataBase` = объект из которого данные берутся (в данном случае `nonclient`).

```
function setList(exportList, dataBase){

    exportList.textContent = '';
    let blankOpt = document.createElement('option');
    blankOpt.textContent='Выберите значение';
    blankOpt.className += 'grey';
    exportList.appendChild(blankOpt);

    for (i in dataBase)  {


        let descriptionOption = document.createElement('option');
        descriptionOption.textContent=dataBase[i].description;
        descriptionOption.className += 'divider';
        exportList.appendChild(descriptionOption);

        for (let j=0; j<dataBase[i].length; j++)  {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.setAttribute('ref', dataBase[i][j]);
                console.log('opt.ref =',opt.ref);

                opt.textContent=(dataBase[i][j].name);
                exportList.appendChild(opt);
        }  
    }
}
```

Используемая база данных

```
nonclient = {};

nonclient.yl = [

{
    name:"ООО «КБМ»",
    inn:"5018048203",
    ogrn:"1025002031405",
    address:"141075, Московская обл., г. Королев, пр. Космонавтов, д. 12А",
    address1:"129110, г. Москва, ул. Гиляровского д. 65, стр. 1, пом. XVI Ч., ком. 39, эт. 5",
    nameLong:"ООО Компания «Большая Медведица»"
},

{
    name:"ООО «АТЕ ФУД»",
    inn:"7731284520",
    ogrn:"1157746508040",
    address:"121596, Город Москва, Улица Горбунова, Дом 2, Строение 204, Комната 48"    
},

{
    name:"ООО «Смартори»",
    inn:"7733223201",
    ogrn:"1157746154312",
    address:"125445, город Москва, шоссе Ленинградское, дом 112, корпус 4"  
}

]

nonclient.fl = [

{
    name:'Петров Петр Петрович',
    address:'г. Сочи ул. Зеленая д. 25'
},

{
    name:'Сидоров Сидор Сидорович',
    address:'г. Нарьян-Мар Ленинский проспект д.1'
}
]

nonclient.au = [
{
    name:'Михайлов Михаил Михайлович',
    inn:'987654321',
    sro:'Союз Арбитражных управляющих г. Бердянска',
    address:'г. Бердянск, а/я "Михайлов М.М."'
}
]

nonclient.allegiance ='nonclient'

nonclient.yl.property='yl';
nonclient.yl.description=' - Организации - ';

nonclient.fl.property='fl';
nonclient.fl.description=' - Физические лица - ';

nonclient.au.property='au';
nonclient.au.description=' - Арбитражные управляющие - ';

Object.defineProperty(nonclient, 'allegiance', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.yl, 'property', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.yl, 'description', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.fl, 'property', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.fl, 'description', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.au, 'property', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(nonclient.au, 'description', {enumerable: false});
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть на реализацию раскрывающегося списка?

Comment: @AlexandTovmach Добавил на страницу. Там на самом деле все немного сложнее чем описано. 3 массива входят в один объект, объекты также содержат переменые `description`, которые хранят описание для заголовков и `property` чтобы подставлять их значение в `value` в соответствии с каждым массивом т.е. `yl1`, `yl2`, `yl3`, `fl1`, `fl2`, `au1` и т.д.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал изменить структуру, чтобы не брать данные из трех массивов, а сделать один массив объектов с флагами (*divider*, *parent_id*, *id*). Так проще рендерить и проще получать значения

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach как это должно выглядеть, если схематично? если физ.лица будут в одном массиве с юр. лицами это нужно будет каждый раз сортировать данные прежде чем их куда-то передавать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```js
const selectEl = document.querySelector("select");

const organisations = [
  {
    name: "ООО «КБМ»",
    inn: "5018048203",
    ogrn: "1025002031405",
    address: "141075, Московская обл., г. Королев, пр. Космонавтов, д. 12А",
    address1: "129110, г. Москва, ул. Гиляровского д. 65, стр. 1, пом. XVI Ч., ком. 39, эт. 5",
    nameLong: "ООО Компания «Большая Медведица»"
  },

  {
    name: "ООО «АТЕ ФУД»",
    inn: "7731284520",
    ogrn: "1157746508040",
    address: "121596, Город Москва, Улица Горбунова, Дом 2, Строение 204, Комната 48"
  },

  {
    name: "ООО «Смартори»",
    inn: "7733223201",
    ogrn: "1157746154312",
    address: "125445, город Москва, шоссе Ленинградское, дом 112, корпус 4"
  }
]

const yl = [
  {
    name: "ООО «КБМ»",
    inn: "5018048203",
    ogrn: "1025002031405",
    address: "141075, Московская обл., г. Королев, пр. Космонавтов, д. 12А",
    address1: "129110, г. Москва, ул. Гиляровского д. 65, стр. 1, пом. XVI Ч., ком. 39, эт. 5",
    nameLong: "ООО Компания «Большая Медведица»"
  },

  {
    name: "ООО «АТЕ ФУД»",
    inn: "7731284520",
    ogrn: "1157746508040",
    address: "121596, Город Москва, Улица Горбунова, Дом 2, Строение 204, Комната 48"
  },

  {
    name: "ООО «Смартори»",
    inn: "7733223201",
    ogrn: "1157746154312",
    address: "125445, город Москва, шоссе Ленинградское, дом 112, корпус 4"
  }
]

const fl = [
  {
    name: 'Петров Петр Петрович',
    address: 'г. Сочи ул. Зеленая д. 25'
  },

  {
    name: 'Сидоров Сидор Сидорович',
    address: 'г. Нарьян-Мар Ленинский проспект д.1'
  }
]

const au = [
  {
    name: 'Михайлов Михаил Михайлович',
    inn: '987654321',
    sro: 'Союз Арбитражных управляющих г. Бердянска',
    address: 'г. Бердянск, а/я "Михайлов М.М."'
  }
];

const extendWithData = (newData, parentName, parentId) => {
  return [
    {
      id: parentId,
      name: parentName,
      isDivider: true
    },
    ...newData.map(el => ({...el, parentId}))
  ]
};

const optionList = [
  ...extendWithData(organisations, "- Организации -", "orgs"),
  ...extendWithData(yl, "- Юр. лица -", "yls"),
  ...extendWithData(fl, "- Физ. лица -", "fls"),
  ...extendWithData(au, "- Арбитражные управляющие -", "aus"),
];

const renderList = (element, data) => {
  element.textContent = '';
  data = [
    {
      name: "Выберите значение",
      isPlaceholder: true
    },
    ...data
  ]

  data.forEach(el => {
    const {
      id,
      name,
      parentId,
      isPlaceholder,
      isDivider
    } = el;

    const optionEl = document.createElement('option');
    optionEl.textContent = name;
    isPlaceholder && optionEl.classList.add('grey');
    isDivider && optionEl.classList.add('divider');
    if (!isPlaceholder && !isDivider) {
      /**
       * Не уверен зачем вам хранить данные в таком виде, но оставил на всякий
       */
      optionEl.setAttribute('data-ref', JSON.stringify(el));
      optionEl.value = JSON.stringify(el);
      /**
       * Советую делать так как написано ниже
       *
       * optionEl.setAttribute('data-id', id);
       * optionEl.setAttribute('data-parent_id', parentId);
       */
    }


    element.appendChild(optionEl);
  });
};

renderList(selectEl, optionList);
selectEl.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  /**
   *  Здесь Ваш функцонал
   */
  const value = e.target.value;
  console.log(value);
});
```

```css
.grey {
  color: grey;
}

.divider {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<select></select>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, конечно, но вы написали все продвинутым способом, я так и не пойму: где тут функция eventListener, которая бы выстреливала при изменении выпадающего списка и возвращала бы соответствующий объект с данными, Потому, что в этом как бы был вопрос, спасибо.

Comment: Отредактирую в течение часа

Comment: @IgorCheglakov обновил